# jsTree search textbox does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, jstree-search

I am using jsTree (http://www.jstree.com/plugins/) with below plugins

```
 "plugins" : [ "dnd" , "contextmenu" ,"ui" , "types" ,  "search" ,"sort" ]
```

All plugins are working fine except search.There is no search textbox added above tree to search node.Is there any other dependency to use search in jsTree.
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add in a search box above your tree:

```
<input id="plugins4_q" type="text" placeholder="search">
```

Note that you'll also need to monitor the search box for text entry and pass the data to the jstree search function. Example javascript:

```
var to = false;
  $('#plugins4_q').keyup(function () {
    if(to) { clearTimeout(to); }
    to = setTimeout(function () {
      var v = $('#plugins4_q').val();
      $('#plugins4').jstree('search', v);
    }, 250);
 });
```